# Is using shell commands from PHP/CGI bad practice?

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell, shell-exec

Are shell commands considered a legitimate programming interface?  Specifically, is there anything wrong with executing bash shell commands on a linux application server from PHP pages or CGI files?  Does this introduce efficiency or security issues?

Thanks

Comment: There are two kinds of people. Ones who use a tool and ones who asks if it legitimate

Comment: Anonymous close voters are the bane of SO... please explain yourselves!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Sometimes OK, but...

---

Sometimes it's the best way to solve a problem.

But possible issues are:

***Security***

Look out for [**code injection**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection) if you aren't doing [**taint checking**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taint_checking).

***Performance***

Running shell commands will involving [**forking**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28operating_system%29) the PHP interpreter and executing complex and relatively slow [**system calls**.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) This is OK for a lightly loaded server but won't work for a busy site.

***Synchronization***

Ensuring that things happen in the right order avoids well-known problems called *lost updates*, *dirty reads*, and *incorrect summaries*. While shell commands are not by themselves a cause of any of these things, running them asynchronously can be, and increasing the complexity of your system will make it harder to analyze.

Comment: Sure. To process an image with ugly GD would be Ok, and with swift external imagemagick would be slow, haha

Comment: Using an external ImageMagick may well be superior from a memory usage standpoint as well, as processing images internally can explode the memory footprint of web servers, in fact, I've seen that happen. I did say that "sometimes it's the best way to solve a problem".

Comment: another example will be ffmpeg, not sure how to survive without shell

Comment: Good points here- thanks.  Where can I go to learn more about taint checking in this scenario?

Comment: In the case of ImageMagick it can also be *necessary* to call the command line version since not all features of the various commands actually work from all languages.

Answer (score 0):

If secure application and server, no.